# I connect to the router but cannot connect to the internet Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, internet, troubleshooting

I am having an issue with connecting to internet over my home network. I can definitely connect to the router, I can send ping to the router address, I can even see that my laptop is connected to the router from the interface of the router. I can't get to the router interface via my laptop tho. I get 404 not found error when I try this with my laptop but I can do this with my mobile phone.

I am currently connected to my mobile phone's hotspot. That's the only way I can connect to the internet. I also can't connect to internet using Ethernet cable either.

Things I have tried so far:

I updated the network adapter driver (rtl8821ce)

I checked the journalctl outputs using `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service -f` command. Here is the recent output of it when I try to connect to my home network

```
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0318] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> bound
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0359] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0430] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0435] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0442] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0459] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0460] policy: set 'FiberHGW_ZT5S2F_5GHz' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0472] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mar 30 01:28:41 mete-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1680128921.0478] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Checked `dmesg` output to see if I can notice an error. The recent output was this:

```
[ 1534.788017] rtw_8821ce 0000:0b:00.0: sta ce:a7:7a:44:0c:6c with macid 0 left
[ 1539.477710] wlo1: authenticate with ce:a7:7a:44:0c:6c
[ 1540.136524] wlo1: send auth to ce:a7:7a:44:0c:6c (try 1/3)
[ 1540.141082] wlo1: authenticated
[ 1540.144419] wlo1: associate with ce:a7:7a:44:0c:6c (try 1/3)
[ 1540.150071] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ce:a7:7a:44:0c:6c (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1540.150105] rtw_8821ce 0000:0b:00.0: sta ce:a7:7a:44:0c:6c joined with macid 0
[ 1540.150347] wlo1: associated
```

Checked my firewall using `sudo ufw status` and the output was `Status: inactive`

Tried to change the DNS setting using both Wifi settings on GUI and setting *nameserver* value as 8.8.8.8 on `/etc/resolv.conf/`

Checked the `nmcli device` output and it gave me this:

```
wlo1             wifi      connected    FiberHGW_ZT5S2F_5GHz              
br-07d2482755db  bridge    connected    br-07d2482755db 
br-422e1e73cb6d  bridge    connected    br-422e1e73cb6d 
br-b281592c535c  bridge    connected    br-b281592c535c 
docker0          bridge    connected    docker0         
virbr0           bridge    connected    virbr0          
eno1             ethernet  unavailable  --              
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --              
virbr0-nic       tun       unmanaged    --
```

Checked static IP conflicts using `sudo arp-scan -l` command. There is no conflict

Removed network configurations using `sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*` command

Despite all, I couldn't figure out what the problem is and why I can connect and use internet with no problem with my mobile hotspot but I can't connect to other routers (I tried it with an another modem that works with SIM Card just like a hotspot too. It didn't connect anyway despite I could also connect to that device with my phone).

I am open to any suggestions. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Really obvious thing to check - turn your phone’s mobile data off (so it can’t use its sim) - can it connect to your router and access the internet? At least that will exclude a router problem if you can get online.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and my phone can connect to the internet without mobile data

Comment: What are the IP ranges of your Docker bridges and your other bridges?  If *any* of them conflict with your current IP range you're on or the DNS servers or routes to the gateway OR the router interface, you've got a broken network configuration on your system.  (I ran into this myself with my `docker0` bridge creating a `172.17` range IP that conflicted hard with my own network and i had to make changes to my config for Docker to use different ranges)  Include the output of `sudo ip -4 route list` and the private IP range of your wifi/ethernet network.

Comment: Yes! You are right. One of the docker images was conflicting with my ip address range on my home network. I am writing down what I have done so other people that might have the same problem can solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue thanks to Thomas Ward's comment. Here is step by step guide:

First, checked the Docker bridges using `sudo docker network ls`

Then, I checked my current IP range and DNS servers using `ip addr show`.
And also checked ip v4 routes by using `ip -4 route list` (or you can use `ip route show`).

To see the ip range of the docker networks, I used `sudo docker network inspect <network_name> | grep Subnet` command. One of them was starting with 192 despite others were fine. For example
`bridge` network subnet is `"172.17.0.0/16"`,
`tut_default` network subnet is `"172.19.0.0/16"`,
`mynet` network subnet is `192.168.1.0/24`

`192.168.1.0/24` is also my home network's ip range. The output of `ip route show` is this:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-422e1e73cb6d proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-07d2482755db proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.33 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

wlo1 is the wifi network interface of Ubuntu. So, I was using wlo1 interface which has `192.168.1.0/24` CIDR notation.

Therefore, I deleted the `mynet` network using `sudo docker network rm mynet` command. If you want to use your docker network anyway, you can reinstall the network by also mentioning the ip address range. For example, I could type `sudo docker network create --subnet=172.25.0.0/16 mynet` for the `mynet` after I deleted it using `sudo docker rm mynet`command.

I hope it helps!